# ASP.Net Website - Server.Transfer with preserveForm=True triggers stackoverflow when transfering to the page that's already active

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, stack-overflow

I recently encountered a bug in my workplace where Server.Transferring to the page that's already active triggers a StackOverflow if the preserveForm param is True.

Example button that would trigger an overflow:

```vb
Private Sub bugTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bugTest.Click
    Server.Transfer("current aspx page", True)
End Sub
```

I know that the problem can be avoided by setting preserveForm to false or using Response.Redirect instead, but I was hoping to get a better understanding of why the bug happens in the first place.

I do have some theories about what might cause it but I don't feel confident enough in any of them to actually explain the cause to my coworkers, and my boss would really like to understand why the bug happens.